# In JSF, how to get a property of a managed bean using ELResolver

Tags: java, jsf, el, managed-bean

I am working on a method in a library.  The method is passed a bean name and property name, and I would like to use ELResolver to retrieve the value of the property from the bean specified.  Since the code is in a library (and for flexibility), the code doesn't have the bean name hard-coded in it.

Here is the code I am using:

```
elResolver.getValue( facesContext.getELContext(), elResolver.getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, myBean ), beanProperty )
```

The bean and properties are specified by `myBean` and `beanProperty`.

This seems to work, but is there a better way?  I am using JSF 1.2 at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'better'?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct way to retrieve the value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks fine. Another way is

```
Object value = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(
    context, String.format("#{%s.%s}", myBean, beanProperty), Object.class);
```

Comment: Great, that's just what I was looking for